# MySQL Query- Issue while using like operator

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `names` and in that table there is a field `info` data is like this:

```
ID    info
1    'alpha,romeo,ciera,delta'
2    'testing,temp,total'
```

I am trying to create a select query.

```
select * from names where info like '%$var%'
```

`$var` is data from php.

> Problem is i want exact match. If i use above query and in $var if
>   data is `rome` then it also return row of romeo.

one more example-

data in table is `testing,temp,total`
user input data is `test` then it also return `testing`

i tried

```
select * from names where info like '$var%'
```

and

```
select * from names where info like '%$var'
```

but it didn't return data as i expected.

Please advise how can i achieve this.

**Note- :** This is an example i am not using mysql as its depreciated. I am using mysqli

Comment: Provide your PHP variable that contains sql query. like `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM....'`

Comment: btw I think you mean `Sierra`  for `S` or `Charlie`  for `C`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza does it matter?

Comment: Why down voting. Please explain.

Comment: provide a var_dump of VAR and the echo the final sql

Comment: The downvote was because your question wasnt clear, see how a little format make it more clear what you have now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append `,` at begin and end of your target search string.

And then make sure your source string also has those `,`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbcc4f/6)**

```
select * 
from names 
where  concat( ',', info , ',') like 
       concat( '%,', $var, ',%')
```

The problem is this wont use any index. You should go for `FULL TEXT` search

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 2):

Use `,` in your query to use it as a delimiter and use multiple conditions to account for the "edge cases".

```
SELECT *
FROM names
WHERE
    info LIKE '%,$var,%' OR
    info LIKE '$var,%' OR
    info LIKE '%,$var' OR
    info = '$var'
```

If you have rows with `info` column:

> alpha,**romeo**,ciera,delta
>   testing,temp,total
>   **rome**
>   foo,test,bar
>   berlin,paris,madrid,london,**rome**
>   venice,milano,**rome**,firence
>   black,**crome**
>   **rome**,fome,mome,kome,kome

Query with `$var` as `"rome"` will select:

> **rome**
>   berlin,paris,madrid,london,**rome**
>   venice,milano,**rome**,firence
>   **rome**,fome,mome,kome,kome

But not:

> alpha,**romeo**,ciera,delta
>   black,**crome**

Comment: field values could be more its not only 3 words. I don't think your answer will work.

Comment: I tried and it worked. Your answer is correct but Juan answer is also worked and it is bit smaller than you. I voted up your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Problem is **i want exact match.** If i use above query and in $var if data is rome then it also return row of romeo.

Don't use the `LIKE` operator, use exact match operator `=`

```
select * from names where info = '$var'
```

Comment: i don't think = will work because in field there would be multiple values and  $var contain single word.

Comment: being honest if you want exact match = is what you need. if you need multiple values inside a field.. then you need a FULL TEXT search

Comment: oh, I didn't realize you had CSV's stuffed inside your column. this is a losing battle. [normalize your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) by putting all those `alpha,romeo,ciera,delta` in their own record in a separate table. Then make a [`junction table`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) with ID's linking the two tables.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Voted up.